# Is there a way to know which column gave a result in a mysql php query?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to know which column gave a result in a mysql php query?

Why am I asking this?

I'm building a search engine for my website and I want to query the columns posts.Title and categoris.Category.

Something like:

$con being the db connection
$search being the input on my typeahead.

```
$q= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT posts.title , categories.Category FROM posts, categories WHERE posts.title LIKE '%$search%' OR categories.Category LIKE '%$search%' ");
```

So, if I query 'monkey' the result is, let's say for example, this json output:

```
{"title":"NASA sent a monkey to space","Category":"Technology"}
```

In this case I wanted to user the 'title' row only on my typehead result. For doing that I need to know if the query has found his result on the title column or in the category column.

Is it possible to know which has done this?

Comment: Check it one more time in php.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it.

Comment: Check which value matches the search criteria, in php.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**No**. It it is impossible to find out which condition was fullfilled to get your data.

You probably should use 2 seperate queries in your php script and let each of them run seperatly.

You cold also use only one, and search for the passed steing in the returned databwith php, so you can find the field that contains your keywors.

Comment: Actually using the sugestion of zerkms I was almost able to filter on which column came (just needed to remove the duplicates but then I decided to change the code a bit and no longer have that problem ).

It's a bit late here in Portugal and I still do have a bit of coding to do before going to bed but I might be able to post today what I was doing and where I stopped so if anyone has this need can resume the work from there